# Set all numpy array values to x if 2 conditions met

Tags: python, numpy

In a numpy array I want to set all values to `x` if the element value does not equal `y` or `z`.

I've tried the following but it fails with the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
# set all values in my_array to -5 if they do not equal -1 or 45
my_array[my_array != -1 and my_array != 45] = -5
```

Comment: `my_array[(my_array != -1) & (my_array != 45)]` numpy uses `&` for `and` and you have to put `()` around each expression for precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator `&` to specify you want the AND to apply coordinate-wise.

```
my_array[(my_array != -1) & (my_array != 45)] = -5
```

Comment: You can certainly use `logical_and()` but `numpy` does support using `&` operator - you just have to put `()` around each expression.

Comment: Good point. Dunno why I always forget about that. It just came up in a pandas question too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `()` for the multiple conditions. Just correcting your code:

```
my_array[(my_array != -1) & (my_array != 45)] = -5
```

This works, here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 4))
print(a)

array([[3, 0, 3, 2],
       [1, 4, 0, 3],
       [2, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 4],
       [1, 4, 4, 2]])
```

Now, let's apply our condition.

```
a[(a > 3) & (a==4)] = -101

print(a) 

array([[   3,    0,    3,    2],
       [   1, -101,    0,    3],
       [   2, -101,    3,    2],
       [   3, -101,    1, -101],
       [   1, -101, -101,    2]])
```

Which essentially changed the value.